# Jest+vue: "Cannot find module ....vue"

Tags: vue.js, jestjs

I'm really just trying to have a skeleton of a jest+vue for my library and quickly get this error.
I know the structure is not the usual jest structure, I here try to describe one test with an auxiliary control.

Here is the content of my `test` folder: `arrays.specs.ts` and `arrays.vue`

Here is the config:

```js
module.exports = {
  moduleFileExtensions: [
    "js",
    "ts",
    "vue"
  ],
  roots: [
    "<rootDir>/test"
  ],
  testEnvironment: "jest-environment-jsdom",
  testMatch: [
    "**/?(*.)+(spec|test).[tj]s?(x)"
  ],
  transform: {
    ".*\\.(vue)$": "vue-jest",
    ".*\\.(ts)$": "ts-jest"
  },
};
```

I have installed these 3 packages: `@vue/test-utils`, `ts-jest` and `vue-jest`

Now, with this, I still end up with this error when running jest:

```
    test/arrays.spec.ts:4:20 - error TS2307: Cannot find module './arrays.vue'.

    import Arrays from './arrays.vue'
```

I really don't see what I am missing.

Comment: Does this issue help? : https://github.com/kulshekhar/ts-jest/issues/875

Comment: No, I can import `ts` modules, the problem occurs only with Vue modules

Comment: @eddow - I don't suppose you remember how you fixed this issue? I seem to have the same problem.

Comment: does `"moduleNameMapper": { "^@/(.*)$": "<rootDir>/src/$1" }` help?

Comment: moduleNameMapper by @daigorocub suggestion worked for me

Answer (score 8):

You might be missing a 'shim' file. Place this in your 'src' directory:

`shims-vue.d.ts`

```
declare module '*.vue' {
  import Vue from 'vue';
  export default Vue;
}
```

Comment: It worked for normal files, but for .spec.ts files it does not work

Answer (score 3):

In my case, the problem was that the file `shims-vue.d.ts` was in the root directory of the project. I had to move it to `./src` in order to be able to load `.vue` modules.

Answer (score 2):

If the error **Cannot find module issue** in vue jest testing occures, set the **preset** property of **jest.config.js** file as below.

```
module.exports = {
  preset: '@vue/cli-plugin-unit-jest/presets/typescript-and-babel',
  testEnvironment: 'node'
}
```